# merge two data sets based on the information from two columns

Tags: r

I have two large data sets like these:

```
df1 <- data.frame(subject = c(rep(1, 15), rep(2, 14)), day =c(0,0,1,1,1,2,3,15,15,16,16,17,17,18,19,0,0,1,1,2,3,15,15,16,16,17,17,18,19),stime=c('4/16/2012 6:25','4/16/2012 7:01','4/17/2012 7:22','4/17/2012 7:45','4/17/2012 8:13','4/18/2012 6:50','4/19/2012 6:55','5/1/2012 6:28','5/1/2012 7:00','5/2/2012 6:28','5/2/2012 7:00','5/3/2012 6:22','5/3/2012 7:00','5/4/2012 6:26','5/5/2012 6:47','4/23/2012 5:56','4/23/2012 6:30','4/24/2012 6:55','4/24/2012 7:20','4/25/2012 6:32','4/26/2012 6:28','5/8/2012 5:54','5/8/2012 6:30','5/9/2012 5:55','5/9/2012 6:30','5/10/2012 5:55','5/10/2012 6:30','5/11/2012 6:41','5/12/2012 6:46'))

df2 <- data.frame(subject = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10)), day =c(1,1,2,3,9,12,15,15,16,17,1,1,2,3,9,13,15,15,16,17),dtime=c('4/17/2012 7:15','4/17/2012 7:15','4/17/2012 7:15','4/17/2012 7:15','4/25/2012 7:15','4/28/2012 7:15','5/1/2012 7:15','5/1/2012 7:15','5/1/2012 7:15','5/1/2012 7:15','4/24/2012 6:45','4/24/2012 6:45','4/24/2012 6:45','4/24/2012 6:45','5/2/2012 7:00','5/6/2012 6:45','5/8/2012 6:45','5/8/2012 6:45','5/8/2012 6:45','5/8/2012 6:45'))
```

...

I want to merge the two data sets so that the 'dtime' in df2 could match the 'subject' and 'day' in df1, and fill out the missing value with '.' in df1, the row number should be the same as df1. The expected output should look like this:

```
merged <- data.frame(subject = c(rep(1, 15), rep(2, 14)), day =c(0,0,1,1,1,2,3,15,15,16,16,17,17,18,19,0,0,1,1,2,3,15,15,16,16,17,17,18,19),stime=c('4/16/2012 6:25','4/16/2012 7:01','4/17/2012 7:22','4/17/2012 7:45','4/17/2012 8:13','4/18/2012 6:50','4/19/2012 6:55','5/1/2012 6:28','5/1/2012 7:00','5/2/2012 6:28','5/2/2012 7:00','5/3/2012 6:22','5/3/2012 7:00','5/4/2012 6:26','5/5/2012 6:47','4/23/2012 5:56','4/23/2012 6:30','4/24/2012 6:55','4/24/2012 7:20','4/25/2012 6:32','4/26/2012 6:28','5/8/2012 5:54','5/8/2012 6:30','5/9/2012 5:55','5/9/2012 6:30','5/10/2012 5:55','5/10/2012 6:30','5/11/2012 6:41','5/12/2012 6:46'),dtime =c('.','.','4/17/2012 7:15','4/17/2012 7:15','4/17/2012 7:15','4/17/2012 7:15','4/17/2012 7:15','5/1/2012 7:15','5/1/2012 7:15','5/1/2012 7:15','5/1/2012 7:15','5/1/2012 7:15','5/1/2012 7:15','.','.','.','.','4/24/2012 6:45','4/24/2012 6:45','4/24/2012 6:45','4/24/2012 6:45','5/8/2012 6:45','5/8/2012 6:45','5/8/2012 6:45','5/8/2012 6:45','5/8/2012 6:45','5/8/2012 6:45','.','.'))
```

...

I tried to use `merge(df1, df2, by = c('subject', 'day'))`, but its not working well, it produced extra rows that I do not want.

Does anyone have idea about realizing this?

Comment: `its not working well` you mean because it drops the rows that are missing in df2?

Comment: it produced extra rows that I do not want, the row number should be the same as df1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
result <- merge(df1,unique(df2),by=c("subject","day"),all.x=T)
result$dtime <- as.character(result$dtime)
result[is.na(result$dtime),]$dtime="."
```

Some notes:

1. You don't need the `by=...` argument in `merge(...)` because the default is to merge on all common columns (which, in your case, are `subject` and `day`). I included it for clarity.
2. The other answer produced extra columns because some of the rows in `df2` are duplicated. In this case we can deal with that using `unique(...)`, but usually this is a symptom of a bigger problem. You should really look into why there are duplicated rows...
3. The way you have it set up, `dtime` is a factor. You have to convert that to character before you can set the NA's to something else.

Finally, if your datasets are indeed large (millions of rows), then consider using data tables. This will be *much faster*.

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(df1,key="subject,day")
dt2 <- data.table(unique(df2),key="subject,day")
result <- dt2[dt1]
result[is.na(dtime),dtime:="."]
head(result)
#    subject day          dtime          stime
# 1:       1   0              . 4/16/2012 6:25
# 2:       1   0              . 4/16/2012 7:01
# 3:       1   1 4/17/2012 7:15 4/17/2012 7:22
# 4:       1   1 4/17/2012 7:15 4/17/2012 7:45
# 5:       1   1 4/17/2012 7:15 4/17/2012 8:13
# 6:       1   2 4/17/2012 7:15 4/18/2012 6:50
```